# How to properly fit a filled Image in its bounds on SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, lazyvgrid

I have to fix a problem with Images on SwiftUI. I currently have to fill the images I receive in a certain vertical container, which are the cells of a LazyVGrid, but the problem is that the tappable area expands over the designated one.

I used the Accessibility Inspector, and I found out that the area in excess is due the Images. (screenshot attached)

The code I'm using is something similar to the following:

```
Image(uiImage: image.image)
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .frame(
        maxWidth: width,
        maxHeight: height
    )
    .clipped()
```

I thought that by having the frames and the clipped method I could get rid of this problem, but that's not the case unless I'm using some squared images. Any idea of what could work to fix this problem? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `.contentShape(Rectangle())` at the bottom:

```
            Image(uiImage: image.image)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(
                    maxWidth: width,
                    maxHeight: height
                )
                .clipped()
                .contentShape(Rectangle())    // <- Here!
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap content in Geometry Reader and you need to know the aspect ratio like I set 720/460 below

```
GeometryReader { gr in
       Image(uiImage: image.image)
            .resizable()
             .aspectRatio(720/460, contentMode: .fit)
          }
        .clipped()
        .aspectRatio(720/460, contentMode: .fit)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fix it. The aspect ratio is already applied and I need a fill